# Como resolver o erro de módulo não encontrado? (Instalando opencv-python)

Tags: python, opencv

Instalei o opencv-python pelo Anaconda, só que quando tento importá-lo é apresentado o erro:

```
DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

A um tempo também estava tendo problemas para utilizar o OpenCV utilizando o IDE PyCharm e segui os paços a baixo para resolver:

Passos a seguir:

1 - Instalar o Python 2.7.10 ou outra versão compativel 
2 - Instale o Pycharm (se você ainda não o fez)
3 - Baixe e instale o executável OpenCV.
4 - Adicionar OpenCV no caminho do sistema (%OPENCV_DIR%=/path/of/opencv/directory)
5 - Vá para a pasta C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86 e copie o arquivo cv2.pyd.
6 - Vá para o diretório C: \ Python27 \ DLLs e cole o arquivo cv2.pyd.
7 - Vá para o diretório C: \ Python27 \ Lib \ site-packages e cole o arquivo cv2.pyd.
8 - Vá para PyCharm IDE e vá para DefaultSettings> PythonInterpreter.
9 - Selecione o Python que você instalou na primeira etapa.
10 - Instale os pacotes numpy, matplotlib e pip no pycharm.
11 - Reinicie seu PyCharm.
12 - O PyCharm agora tem a biblioteca OpenCV instalada e funcionando.

Espero ter conseguido lhe ajudar.